# Nome do atributo referente a chave secundária em um modelo no Django

Tags: python, django, framework

Eu tenho um problema com um banco de dados importado para o Django 1.6.5. Neste banco de dados as colunas seguem o padrão: id_city, name, id_state e etc. Porém, o django não lidou bem com isso deixando a classe assim:

```
class City(models.Model):
    id_city = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', db_column='id_state', blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'city'
```

Para acessar o campo id_state da tabela através do modelo eu tenho duas alternativas:

1. city.state_id
2. city.state.id_state

Na primeira alternativa é confuso trabalhar com um nome diferente do nome no banco e, na segunda alternativa, é necessária uma consulta a mais para saber um único campo.

Procurei na documentação mas, não achei uma forma simples de usar o atributo da forma como está no banco, que seria assim:

```
city.id_state
```

Comment: O que esta querendo entender é o conceito de relacionamento entre uma tabela com a outra ? relacionamente 1 para 1 ,1 para muitos ? seria esse o que deseja ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar

```
city.state.pk
```

O Django por padrão sempre cria internamente um atributo `pk` que aponta para chave primaria daquela model, isso pode ser inclusive usado no metodo `get`

```
State.objects.get(pk=123)
```

Comment: O meu problema é com chave secundária e city.state.pk equivale à city.state.id_state até onde sei. Então é necessária mais uma consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa criar o campo id_city. Pois, o Django já cria ele para você. O teu modelo fica mais limpo e você pode acessa-lo mais facilmente assim:

```
city.id
city.state.id
```

Você não vai conseguir acessar o id_state da forma que você quer: `city.id_state`, pois o atributo referente à classe State que você tem na classe City é state, mesmo o seu db_column sendo ='id_state'.